# How to fix react-native-bouncy-checkbox issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

> An unexpected error occurred: "could not find a copy of
> react-native-vector-icons to link in ....
> node_modules\react-native-bouncy-checkbox\node_modules".

*react-native-vector-icons already installed*

Hi developers
I am getting while installing

```
yarn add react-native-bouncy-checkbox
```

---

---

TLDR

PS D:\Ctrl + O\Codingboyo\AppDevelopment\ReactNative\LearningProjects\UberEats\ubereats> yarn add react-native-bouncy-checkbox

yarn add v1.22.17

[1/4] Resolving packages...

[2/4] Fetching packages...

[3/4] Linking dependencies...

warning "react-native > react-native-codegen > jscodeshift@0.11.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/preset-env@^7.1.6".

warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >
= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".

warning "react-native-bouncy-checkbox > react-native-bottom-search-bar@0.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "@freakycoder/react-native-helpers@0.0.21".

error An unexpected error occurred: "could not find a copy of react-native-vector-icons to link in D:\Ctrl + O\Codingboyo\AppDevelopment\ReactNative\LearningProj
ects\UberEats\ubereats\node_modules\react-native-bouncy-checkbox\node_modules".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "D:\Ctrl + O\Codingboyo\AppDevelopment\ReactNative\LearningProjects\U
berEats\ubereats\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when installing/updating libraries. Just close all your metro bundlers/consoles and start fresh.